# Is there a way of simultaneously labelling 3 lines produced from a matrix?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Looking to add axes labels and line labels to this code: Its for a 3 level energy system and produces 3 lines from plt.show(), so I want to basically give each line a label according to which it started out as..

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
E1 = 0.3 #Energy values
E2 = 0.2
E3 = 0.7

t = np.array([0]) #for ze time
   
w12 = abs(E2-E1) #omega values
w23 = abs(E3-E2)
w13 = abs(E3-E1)
t0=0 #start time
dt=1 #delta interval size
T=30 #end time

Nt = int(T/dt) #steps within interval up to T

#Start condition
N01=0
N02=0       #changing the order of the 1s and 0s adjust which energy levels fill first, and change the graph.
N03=1

N = np.array([[N01,N02,N03]]) #Vector of start values for N
N_sum = np.array(N01+N02+N03)
W = np.array([[-w12,0,w13],[w12,-w23,0],[0,w23,-w13],]) #matrix of frequencies for multiplying N

for i in range(1,Nt):
    tempo = N[i-1] + dt * W@N[i-1] #order of @ matmul product changes the max of each line
    N = np.vstack((N, tempo)) #vertical stack of the arrays 
    t = np.append(t, t[0] + i*dt) #increment time as N increments
plt.plot(t,N) #order of plotting, first x axis, second y axis (realised after vertical graph)
plt.show() #now need to add labels to axis etc.
```

Comment: Would adding ``label`` in ``plt.plot(t, N, label=['a', 'b', 'c'])`` and then adding ``plt.legend()`` the next line (before ``plt.show()``) work for you?

Comment: Ah perfect! since my plot is of a 3 item "array" then making the label an array as well worked :D